# Chartjs Stacked bar have a stack id per x value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to make a chart, where a difference dataset is always filling the blank between the two other datasets. But the problem I am having is, that I can set a stack id per dataset, but not per individual date. I am hoping there is another method to achieve what I want.
I want it to look like [the second dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8V4e.png) But due to the stack id applying to the whole dataset, the difference dataset is on top of the higher data point.

Here is my code with the values of the database already inserted with php, so you have some example values:
This is my JavaScript part:

```
function ConvertMinutes(num) {
  d = Math.floor(num / 1440); // 60*24
  h = Math.floor((num - (d * 1440)) / 60);
  m = Math.round(num % 60);

  if (d > 0) {
    return (d + " Tage, " + h + " Stunden, " + m + " Minuten");
  } else if (h > 0) {
    return (h + " Stunden, " + m + " Minuten");
  } else {
    return (m + " Minuten");
  }
}

var myChart = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(myChart, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['2021-01-26', '2021-01-27', '2021-01-28', '2021-01-29', '2021-01-30', '2021-01-31', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-02', '2021-02-03', '2021-02-04', '2021-02-05', ],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Emil",
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
      data: [
        716, 755, 1681, 890, 482, 494, 753, 364, 832, 889, 702,
      ],
      stack: 2
    }, {
      label: "Luis",
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
      data: [
        716, 974, 1006, 1133, 551, 638, 663, 288, 754, 0, 45,
      ],
      stack: 1
    }, {
      label: "Differenz",
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,255,0)',
      data: [
        0, 219, 675, 243, 69, 144, 90, 76, 78, 889, 657,
      ],
      stack: 2,
    }],
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Onlinezeit der letzten 10 Tage im Vergleich'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
      callbacks: {
        label: function(t, d) {
          var data1 = parseInt(d.datasets[0].data[t.index]);
          var label1 = d.datasets[0].label;
          var data2 = parseInt(d.datasets[1].data[t.index]);
          var label2 = d.datasets[1].label;
          var proz = 0.0;
          if (data1 > data2) {
            proz = Math.round(((data1 - data2) / data1) * 100, 2);
          } else {
            proz = Math.round(((data2 - data1) / data2) * 100, 2);
          }
          if (t.datasetIndex === 0) {
            if (data1 >= data2) {
              return label1 + ": " + ConvertMinutes(data1) + " (+" + proz + "%)";
            } else {
              return label1 + ": " + ConvertMinutes(data1) + " (-" + proz + "%)";
            }
          } else if (t.datasetIndex === 1) {
            if (data2 >= data1) {
              return label2 + ": " + ConvertMinutes(data2) + " (+" + proz + "%)";
            } else {
              return label2 + ": " + ConvertMinutes(data2) + " (-" + proz + "%)";
            }
          } else {
            return d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label + ": " + proz + "% (" + d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].data[t.index] + "min)";
          }
        },
        /*labelTextColor:function(t, c){
            console.log(t);
            console.log(c.config.data.datasets[t.datasetIndex].data[t.index]);
        }*/
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          //macht es so, dass der Graph bei 0 anfängt
          beginAtZero: true,
          //stepSize: 1,
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return value + " min";
          }
          //max: 4
        },
        //stacked: true
      }]
    },
  }
});
```

And this my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vergleich zwischen: <?php echo $userdata[$cldbids[0]]["name"] . " & " . $userdata[$cldbids[1]]["name"];?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container b" style="width: 1200px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two distinct datasets for the differences as shown in your amended code below.

```js
function ConvertMinutes(num) {
  d = Math.floor(num / 1440); // 60*24
  h = Math.floor((num - (d * 1440)) / 60);
  m = Math.round(num % 60);

  if (d > 0) {
    return (d + " Tage, " + h + " Stunden, " + m + " Minuten");
  } else if (h > 0) {
    return (h + " Stunden, " + m + " Minuten");
  } else {
    return (m + " Minuten");
  }
}

var myChart = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(myChart, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['2021-01-26', '2021-01-27', '2021-01-28', '2021-01-29', '2021-01-30', '2021-01-31', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-02', '2021-02-03', '2021-02-04', '2021-02-05', ],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Emil",
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
        data: [
          716, 755, 1681, 890, 482, 494, 753, 364, 832, 889, 702,
        ],
        stack: 2
      }, {
        label: "Luis",
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
        data: [716, 974, 1006, 1133, 551, 638, 663, 288, 754, 0, 45],
        stack: 1
      }, {
        label: "Differenz",
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,255,0)',
        data: [0, 219, 0, 243, 69, 144, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        stack: 2,
      },
      {
        label: "Differenz",
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,255,0)',
        data: [0, 0, 675, 0, 0, 0, 90, 76, 78, 889, 657],
        stack: 1,
      }
    ],
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Onlinezeit der letzten 10 Tage im Vergleich'
    },
    legend: {
      labels: {
        filter: legendItem => legendItem.datasetIndex < 3
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
      callbacks: {
        label: function(t, d) {
          var data1 = parseInt(d.datasets[0].data[t.index]);
          var label1 = d.datasets[0].label;
          var data2 = parseInt(d.datasets[1].data[t.index]);
          var label2 = d.datasets[1].label;
          var proz = 0.0;
          var min = 0;
          if (data1 > data2) {
            proz = Math.round(((data1 - data2) / data1) * 100, 2);
            min = data1 - data2;
          } else {
            proz = Math.round(((data2 - data1) / data2) * 100, 2);
             min = data2 - data1;
          }
          if (t.datasetIndex === 0) {
            if (data1 >= data2) {
              return label1 + ": " + ConvertMinutes(data1) + " (+" + proz + "%)";
            } else {
              return label1 + ": " + ConvertMinutes(data1) + " (-" + proz + "%)";
            }
          } else if (t.datasetIndex === 1) {
            if (data2 >= data1) {
              return label2 + ": " + ConvertMinutes(data2) + " (+" + proz + "%)";
            } else {
              return label2 + ": " + ConvertMinutes(data2) + " (-" + proz + "%)";
            }
          } else if (t.datasetIndex === 2 && data1 < data2) {
            return undefined;
          } else if (t.datasetIndex === 3 && data1 >= data2) {
            return undefined;  
          } else {
            return d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label + ": " + proz + "% (" + min + "min)";
          }
        }
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return value + " min";
          }
        },
      }]
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="120"></canvas>
```