# Minus chartjs between 2 values

Tags: chart.js

My code is

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["2015-01", "2015-02"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Tomatoes',
      data: [12, 19],
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: '# of Oranges',
      data: [10, 19],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

First bar his result is **12 + 10 = 22**, but ¿How can I do that result be 2 instead of 22? I would like to minus 12-10, not sum 12+10

Comment: Why would you want a stacked bar for that, it would totally misinform the numbers. If you want something like that you will need to use a normal bar chart and feed the already parsed data (subtracted values from eachother) into it

Comment: I agree with [LeeLenalee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8682983/leelenalee) that your chart would misinform the user. In case you want to reconsider your approach, this answer may help you to find a different solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66076449/2358409